# Asterisk: how to end frozen calls

Tags: voip, asterisk, sip

Sometimes my voip provider shuts down service without ending calls which are in progress (these calls are incoming to my server and they are coming to queue).
So calls are never gracefully finished, I never get BYE and I have my peers in queue keep being in “in call” state forever. I can only reset their state by restarting asterisk service.

How do I set up asterisk to end this kind of calls automatically? Is there some kind of timeout for this situation?

Comment: I think the solution here should be that you call your VOIP provider and complain about the disconnects in the first place. Solve why it disconnects is a much better solution than to solve the after effects. Its like you get an accident with your car and the door is sheered off. As a result when you drive it gets cold in the car, so the garage offers to install a heater. But if they just put on a new door, problem solved!

Comment: @LPChip will do, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have options

```
rtptimeout=300
rtpholdtimeout=300
```

Not always works, but no other.